# Create a PDF with embeded SWF and FlashVars using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, flex4, flash, flashvars

I would like to generate a PDF with an swf embed into it.
I would also like to make sure the SWF is embedded with a flashvar called XMLDATA which contains charting information.

I would like to achieve this programmatically using c#.

I have found plenty of ways that allow embedding swf, but need one that formally supports the flashvars mechanism.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://fatihsahinbas.blogspot.com/2011/07/itextsharp-swf-view-methods.html

This was the full answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`ItextSharp`](http://itextpdf.com/). I made some research and seems like it provides what you want.

[RichMediaInstance Class](http://api.itextpdf.com/xtra/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/richmedia/RichMediaInstance.html)

[RichMediaParams Class](http://api.itextpdf.com/xtra/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/richmedia/RichMediaParams.html)

Comment: We currently use iTextSharp, which is a port of iTextPDF, sadly it does not have the same functionality as its parent project at least not in full.

Also the class does not exist in the version we have.

Comment: The samples there are from the itextPDF Java based classes.

Comment: Yes, but itextsharp has also both of theses classes.Unfortunately, could not find a documentation for c#.

Comment: I thought so 2, but the intellitext didnt pick them up, will look again if I do find them the bounty is yours.

But so far I cant find a single working example of anyone embedding an swf with a flashvar into a pdf, which is all I need.

Comment: Try `iTextSharp.text.pdf.richmedia.RichMediaInstance` and `iTextSharp.text.pdf.richmedia.RichMediaParams` in C#.

Comment: I have those, unfortunatly the flashvars portion does not work at all...

I literally just need to find a way or any example code to set the Flashvars in PDF using C#...